# Split with underscores within list in column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1  COL2
G1    ['OK_+__SP2','PL_-__SP2']
G2    ['IQO_-__SP1_8','PL2_-__SP2']
G2    ['IRO_+__SP8']
```

and I would like to remove **for each element** of the `COL2`, the part before `__`

and get

```
COL1  COL2
G1    ['SP2','SP2']
G2    ['SP1_8','SP2']
G2    ['SP8']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if necessary convert values to lists:

```
import ast
df['COL2'] = df['COL2'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Then `split` in list comprehension:

```
df['COL2'] = df['COL2'].apply(lambda x: [y.split('__')[-1] for y in x])
print (df)
  COL1          COL2
0   G1    [SP2, SP2]
1   G2  [SP1_8, SP2]
2   G2         [SP8]
```

Or:

```
df['COL2'] = [[y.split('__')[-1] for y in x] for x in df['COL2']]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help